# What does "gallus" mean in English?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, meaning

The scientific name of a chicken is *Gallus Gallus Domesticus*. What does 'gallus' mean?

I think it is related to the Spanish *gallo*.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gallus#Latin

Comment: I think the reason this is getting downvotes is that you seem to be just asking about the meaning of a Latin noun. Did you check a Latin dictionary? If so, what further questions remained for you?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing too exciting, I'm afraid—it means "chicken". Or rather, "rooster", since it's a masculine noun. Its descendants can be seen in e.g. Spanish *gallo* and Portuguese *galo*.

There's also an unrelated noun *Gallus*, meaning "Gaul" (i.e. person from France).

Comment: "Theoretically, the bird could have been denominated 'the Gaulish one' (Gallus), but 
there are no indications that chicken were regarded as having come from Gaul." (de Vaan)